# How do I use JavaScript and print the result in a Kendo UI template?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-dataviz

For example,I use the these codes and it works well and the tooltip show the decimal number like "2.152".

```
  tooltip: {
    visible: true,
    template: "<table style='color:red'><tr><td> #= value #</td></tr></table>"
   }
```

Now I want to use `Math.round()` function for the value of the tooltip,I use like these,but it do not work.It just show the "Math.round(2.152)" string,but I just want show "2".

```
  tooltip: {
    visible: true,
    template: "<table style='color:red'><tr><td>Math.round(#=value#)</td></tr></table>"
   }
```

Comment: Did you try parseInt?

Comment: Yes,but it also do not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to evaluate JS code and print the result, you need to surround the full expression with the delimiters:

```
#= Math.round(value) #
```

Everything outside of that is simply treated as a string.

Answer (score 1):

According to the document [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/templates/overview),if you use javascript,you shuld use `#..#`,try the code again.

```
 tooltip: {
visible: true,
template: "<table style='color:red'><tr><td># Math.round(#=value#) #</td></tr></table>"
```

}

Comment: `#...#` is for observables.   For a Javascript function, see @Lars answer.